# FIPS Capable OpenSSL and `make depend`

Tags: openssl, makefile, fips

I'm trying to build a FIPS Capable OpenSSL for an iDevice. I'm working with the FIPS 2.0 gear, and the 1.0.1 sources. Step 1 is OpenSSL FIPS Object Module, and it went fairly well. Step 2 is FIPS Capable OpenSSL.

To configure FIPS Capable OpenSSL, we perform:

```
./config -no-dtls --with-fiplibdir=/usr/local/ssl/iphoneos/lib
```

`-no-dtls` is required because Apple omitted STCP and friends. I don't want to make STCP and DTLS a dependency in this process, so `-no-dtls` is the obvious choice. In addition, [third party STCP](http://lists.apple.com/archives/macnetworkprog/2008/May/msg00048.html) will surely lack Xcode and cross-compilation support.

However, the `-no-dtls` requires we run `make depend`. `make depend` is causing me:

```
openssl-1.0.1c jwalton$ make depend
making depend in crypto...
../util/domd: line 30: makedepend: command not found
mv: Makefile.new: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [depend] Error 127
make: *** [depend] Error 1
```

I tried finding `makedepend` on this system (2012 MBP, Xcode 4.5), but its MIA:

```
$ find /Applications/Xcode.app/ -name makedepend 2>/dev/null
$ find /usr/ -name makedepend 2>/dev/null
$ find /bin/ -name makedepend 2>/dev/null
$
```

`make depend` is essential here. When I attempt to continue without it, I run into the STCP problem. Hence the requirement:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc -I.. -I../.. -I../modes -I../asn1 -I../evp -I../../include  -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -arch armv7 -O3 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-common   -c -o bss_dgram.o bss_dgram.c
bss_dgram.c:74:26: error: netinet/sctp.h: No such file or directory
bss_dgram.c: In function ‘BIO_new_dgram_sctp’:
bss_dgram.c:843: error: storage size of ‘auth’ isn’t known
bss_dgram.c:860: error: ‘SCTP_AUTH_CHUNK’ undeclared (first use in this function)
bss_dgram.c:860: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
bss_dgram.c:860: error: for each function it appears in.)
bss_dgram.c:860: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct sctp_authchunk’
```

I went to X.org and fetched the package. The package won't build from sources due to missing dependencies. I see this going on ad infinitium (I've been down that road before).

What are my options here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mac OS X 10.8: makedepend?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031513/mac-os-x-10-8-makedepend)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To configure FIPS Capable OpenSSL, we perform:
>
> ```
> ./config -no-dtls --with-fiplibdir=/usr/local/ssl/iphoneos/lib
> ```

Dooh... it should be `./config fips -no-dtls`...