# makedepend missing?

Tags: macos, makefile

OS X 10.8 is missing `makedepend` ([Apple: OpenSSL and `make depend`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14030575/apple-openssl-and-make-depend)). It looks like the last version of OS X that had `makedepend` was 10.7.4 (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/makedepend.1.html).

I can't modify the makefile due to policy, so I tried placing an alias in my `.bash_profile`, but it did not work as expected.

Is anyone aware of an alternative? Does Apple put deprecate packages anywhere? I did not see it on opensource.apple.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two seconds of googling found [this](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=181159), which says that `gcc -M` is equivalent to `makedepend`.

Comment: makedepend does a bunch of argument munging around -M. A few more seconds of googling will reveal 1,000,000 places to download the script.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. "Two seconds of googling found this" - it would be great if it worked. Apparently they are not equivalent, or something else is wrong. I can't modify the makefile due to policy, but I did try adding an alias to .bash_profile, which died. (For S&G, I did try plugging in gcc -M and llvm-ggc -M. Neither worked).

Comment: Aliases aren't used by make, try writing a script (which is what makedepend usually is). And as bmargulies pointed out, you can't just plug it in, you need to do some argument munging.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. "Aliases aren't used by make" - the shell would perform the command substitution (transparent to maker), no?

Answer (score 11):

Did you try:

brew install makedepend

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Installation